# Question about Disconnect Switches

Tags: power, switches, construction

I'm looking at an electrical construction drawing and I just keep forgetting what the disconnect switch notations mean. Refer to the attached image. This is what I'm assuming: the number in the first quadrant of the circle is the number of poles, 3, in this case. Number in the 2nd quadrant is the voltage, 600V, in this case. Number in the 3rd Quadrant is the amperage, 60A, in this case. Number on the 4th Quadrant is the fuse size, 50A, in this case. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[image: Cropped part of referenced drawing]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the answer in the legend. See attached[image]